# manager.emit_all() implementation in Tauri

Tags: rust, tauri

I have a Tauri app and, in main.rs, i have this function

```
fn handle_client(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    // this is a buffer to read data from the client
    let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
    // this read data from the stream and stores it in the buffer
    stream.read(&mut buffer).expect("Failed to read from client!");
    // this converts the data in the buffer into a UTF-8 encoded string
    let request = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer[..]);
    // this print in console the received request
    println!("Received request: {}", request);
    let response_json = json!({
        "message": "Hello, Client!",
        "status": "success"
    });
    let response_body = serde_json::to_string(&response_json).expect("Failed to serialize JSON");
    //let app_handle = app.app_handle();

    app_handle.emit_all("request", "response.json").unwrap();
    let response = format!(
        "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: {}\r\n\r\n{}",
        response_body.len(),
        response_body
    );
    // this write a response to client
    stream.write(response.as_bytes()).expect("Failed to write response!");
}

fn main() {
    thread::spawn(|| {
        // this is a TCP socket server
        let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").expect("Failed to bind address");
        // this print in console the main message
        println!("Server listening on 192.168.1.69:8080");

        // this wait for a client connection    
        for stream in listener.incoming(){
            match stream{
                Ok(stream) => {
                    std::thread::spawn(|| handle_client(stream));
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    eprintln!("Failed to establish connection: {}", e);
                }
            }
        }

    });
    
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");

}
```

I basically need to give to the frontend response_json, and i saw another topic that suggested to implement this funtion:

```
fn function<R: tauri::Runtime>(manager: &impl Manager<R>) {
    manager.emit_all("event", ()).unwrap();
}
```

I tried to call the event in handle_client or i even tried to just have that function alone and a call to that when needed, but I cannot really understand how to implement it.

Comment: If you move the std::thread::spawn into tauri's setup hook (https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/struct.Builder.html#method.setup) you can get an AppHandle via app.handle(), move that handle into your thread and use it to emit your events.